# "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" error in Eclipse, Mac OS X

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

I am unable to post my code as it's homework but whenever I try to build my C++ project, I keep getting these errors. I've looked at many similar questions online and none of the solutions seem to be working. This is what my build console says:

```
15:42:35 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project A5 ****
make all 
Building file: ../ShapesGood.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"ShapesGood.d" -MT"ShapesGood.o" -o "ShapesGood.o" "../ShapesGood.cpp"
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ShapesGood.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

15:42:36 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.290ms)
```

I am using Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0) on a Mac OS Catalina and I the binary parser I'm using is Mach-O 64 Parser. The Source Location has the correct source folder in it.

Comment: Does your project contain a main function?

Comment: Yeah it does contain a main function

Comment: Well then we won't get far unless you post your code.

Comment: From those errors, it does seem like source file which contains you main function is missing.

Comment: Or `_main`, spelled differently.

Comment: It is rather curious that is compiling to an object file *without* the -c flag. Did you modify any build settings, @epmxo?